# VBA help to place the weekday dependent hours into the correct column

Tags: vba, excel

The "Supplier Timesheet Workbook" in cell B12 to B23 there is the date. With the hours worked on that date in cell i12 to i23. The hours need to go in a particular column in the "Master Workbook" depending on which day of the week this was done.

Looking at the two pics below this will make more sense.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code where this needs to go into:

```
Public Sub Consolidate_to_master()
    Dim wksMaster As Worksheet
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Path = "\\ttsnaInbox folder\"  'CHANGE PATH
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")
    Set wksMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' or ThisWorkbook
    i = 3

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        With wkb.Worksheets(1)
            For Each rng In .Range("L12:L23")
                ' if there is a value in the cell
                If rng <> vbNullString Then
                Range(Selection, Cells(Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp)).Select
                    wksMaster.Range("A" & i) = .Range("J8")
                    wksMaster.Range("B" & i) = "1234"
                    wksMaster.Range("C" & i) = .Range("J9")
                    wksMaster.Range("D" & i) = "10"
                    wksMaster.Range("E" & i) = rng
                    wksMaster.Range("F" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("G" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("H" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("I" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("J" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("K" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("L" & i) = ""
                    wksMaster.Range("M" & i) = ""
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With

        wkb.Close True
        Filename = Dir

    Loop
End Sub
```

This is where a weekday function can be inserted but really not sure how to do this.

```
wksMaster.Range("G" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("H" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("I" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("J" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("K" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("L" & i) = ""
wksMaster.Range("M" & i) = ""
```

Comment: Is the bottom image the Master sheet? How are you populating the first 5-6 columns? Populating the correct column should be easy using weekday function to offset from column F. Knowing which row to use is a little more unclear. Does one  simply assign to the next free row? Do the rows just continue being added on or are there a finite number that are populated and then they are overwritten? This question feels like more detail is needed.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it simply using pivot tables.

Get day name using custom formatting 'ddd'([check this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/821-excel-convert-date-to-weekday-month-name.html))

See attached screenshot for similar data.[image]

Comment: Yes if it was one sheet. The Macro reads 100s of supplier timehsheet workbooks and puts them in the master workbook. I need help with the macro.